# Proof that a Function is Entire

Tags: complex-analysis

For every $z \in \mathbb{C}$, let us define
\begin{equation}
H(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{-t} e^{tz} dt.
\end{equation}
I have tried to prove that $H$ is holomorphic in the whole plane and that
\begin{equation}
H(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{n-t} dt,
\end{equation}
but I am stuck. One way would be to prove directly that $H$ is complex-differentiable in the whole plane and 
\begin{equation}
H'(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{1-t} e^{tz} dt,
\end{equation}
and then iterate the argument to compute the higher order derivatives. Another way would be to prove that the series
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{|z|^n}{n!} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{n-t} dt,
\end{equation}
converges for every $z$, since this would justify the interchange of integral and limit, so that 
\begin{equation}
H(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{n-t} dt,
\end{equation}
and clearly $H$ would turn to be analytic in the whole plane. Unfortunately, I couldn't fill the details of the two proofs I have in mind, and I am stuck now. Any help is welcome.

Comment: This is a tricky problem, depending on what you can assume. Before anything else you should show that $H(z)$ is well defined. Assuming that this has been done, the main problem is that we cannot assume that the derivative can go inside the integral! Of course, you can look at any good book on the Laplace transform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yet another approach is using complex contour integrals.

By Morera's theorem, a continuous complex function is entire if its integral over every triangle $\Delta \subset \mathbb C$ equals zero.

Continuity of $H(z)$ follows from the Dominated convergence theorem. To show that $\oint_\Delta H(z)dz = 0$, you may apply the Fubini-Tonelli theorem to each side of $\Delta$ to change the order of integration.

You may also use this interchanging trick to compute the derivatives of $H$ with Cauchy's formula: for point $z$ insinde $\Delta$
$$
H^{(n)}(z) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \oint\limits_{\;\Delta} \frac{H(\zeta)\,d\zeta}{(\zeta-z)^{n+1}}
$$

Comment: How does continuity follow from DCT? Could you pelase elaborate?

Comment: @luka5z, one needs to show, according to the Heine definition of continuity in $\mathbb R^2 = \mathbb C$, that $H(z_n) \rightarrow H(z)$ whenever $z_n \rightarrow z$. And we can bound $t^{-t} e^{tz_n}$ by integrable function, since converging sequence is bounded.

Comment: Just note that $|e^{tz}| \leq e^{t |z|}$.

Answer (score 0):

Now I see how to complete the two sketches of proof I quoted in the post. Let $(w_n)$ a sequence of non-zero complex numbers converging to 0, and such that $|w_n| < M$ for all $n$. Then we have (use the power series expansion of $e^z$ and the convexity of $f(x)=e^{x}$) 
\begin{equation}
\left| \frac{e^{tw_n} - 1}{tw_n} \right| \leq \frac{e^{t |w_n|} - 1}{t|w_n|} \leq e^{t M},
\end{equation}
and so we can use the Dominated Converge Theorem to show that $H$ is complex-differentiable, with
\begin{equation}
H'(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{1-t} e^{tz} dt.
\end{equation}
Now, we can repeat the argument to show that
\begin{equation}
H^{(n)}(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{n-t} e^{tz} dt.
\end{equation}
The other proof I sketched is based on founding a bound for the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty} t^{n-t} dt.
\end{equation}
Define $f_n(t) = t^{n - t/2}$. For each n, $f_n$ is bounded, with maximum $M_n$. If $s_n$ is the point in which $f_n$ reaches the maximum, we have, by using the first order condition $n - s_n/2 = (s_n/2) \log s_n$, $s_n \log(s_n) \leq 2n$, and $M_n =  e^{(s_n/2)\log^2 (s_n)}$, so that $\sqrt[n]{M_n/(n!)} \leq s_n /\sqrt[n]{n!} \leq 2n/(\log(s_n)\sqrt[n]{n!})$, which tends to 0 as $n \rightarrow \infty$, since $s_n \rightarrow \infty$, and $n/ \sqrt[n]{n!} \rightarrow e$ (use Stirling's formula). So by Cauchy-Hadamard formula, the power series
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{n-t} dt,
\end{equation}
has radius of convergence $R=\infty$, and we have done.